# Laravel 5.1 Event Listener Error

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, event-listener

I have the following event listner and subscriber:

```
class UserEventListener
{
    public function onUserLogin(User $user, $remember) {

        $user->last_login_at = Carbon::now();

        $user->save();
    }

    public function onUserLogout(User $user) {}

    public function subscribe($events)
    {
        $events->listen(
            'auth.login',
            'App\Listeners\UserEventListener@onUserLogin'
        );

        $events->listen(
            'auth.logout',
            'App\Listeners\UserEventListener@onUserLogout'
        );

    }
}
```

When I logout I get the following error:

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Listeners\UserEventListener::onUserLogout() must be an instance of App\User, null given
```

The documentation states that on the auth.logout event, parameter $user is available - refer to the section on [Framework Event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events#framework-events)

So why I'm I getting this error?

Comment: Can you show where do you use it?

Comment: Did you add  "use App\User " after namespace?